# Using apply family and multiple functions on lists in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a question following my answer to this question on this question 
[Matching vertex attributes across a list of edgelists R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802228/matching-vertex-attributes-across-a-list-of-edgelists-r/55803129#55803129)

My solution was to use for loops, but we should always try to optimize(vectorize) when we can.

What I'm trying to understand is how I would vectorize the solution I made in the post.

My solution was

```
for(i in 1:length(graph_list)){
  graph_list[[i]]=set_vertex_attr(graph_list[[i]],"gender", value=attribute_df$gender[match(V(graph_list[[i]])$name, attribute_df$names)])
}
```

Ideally we could vectorize this with `lapply` but I'm having some trouble conceiving how to do that. Here's what I've got

```
graph_lists_new=lapply(graph_list, set_vertex_attr, value=attribute_df$gender[match(V(??????????)$name, attribute_df$names)]))
```

What I'm unclear about is what I'd put in the part with the `??????`. The thing inside the `V()` function should be each item in the list, but what I don't get is what I'd put inside when I'm using `lapply`.

All data can be found in the link I posted, but here's the data anyway

```
attribute_df<- structure(list(names = structure(c(6L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("Andy", "Angela", "Eric", "Jamie", "Jeff", "Jim", 
"Pam", "Tim"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    happiness = c(8, 9, 4.5, 5.7, 5, 6, 7, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))



edgelist<-list(structure(list(nominator1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Angela", 
"Jeff", "Jim", "Pam"), class = "factor"), nominee1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Andy", "Angela", "Jeff"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(nominator2 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("Eric", "Jamie", "Oscar", "Tim"), class = "factor"), 
    nominee2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Eric", 
    "Oscar", "Tim"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))

graph_list<- lapply(edgelist, graph_from_data_frame)
```

Comment: `lapply` isn't vectorization---it's just "loop hiding". In this case, your `for` loop is a nicer way to do things than `lapply`. Since you are modifying existing objects, whereas `lapply` probably needs to make a complete copy, your simple `for` loop will almost certainly be more efficient than an `lapply` solution, as well as more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to use `graph_list[[i]]` multiple times in your call, to use `lapply` you need to write a custom function, such as this anonymous function. (It's the same code as your loop, I just wrapped it in `function(x)` and replaced all instances of `graph_list[[i]]` with `x`.)

```
graph_list = lapply(graph_list, function(x)
  set_vertex_attr(x, "gender", value = attribute_df$gender[match(V(x)$name, attribute_df$names)])
)
```

(Note that I didn't test this, but it should work unless I made a typo.)

`lapply` isn't vectorization---it's just "loop hiding". In this case, I think your `for` loop is a nicer way to do things than `lapply`. Especially since you are *modifying* existing objects, your simple `for` loop will probably be more efficient than an `lapply` solution, as well as more readable.

When we talk about vectorization for efficiency, we almost always mean atomic vectors, not `list`s. (It's *vectorization*, after all, not *listization*.) The reason to use `lapply` and related functions (`sapply`, `vapply`, `Map`, most of the `purrr` package) isn't computer efficiency, it's **readability**, and human-efficiency to write.

Let's say you have a list of data frames, `my_list = list(iris, mtcars, CO2)`. If you want to get the number of rows for each of the data frames in the list and store it in a variable, we could use `sapply` or a `for` loop:

```
# easy to write, easy to read
rows_apply = sapply(my_list, nrow)

# annoying to read and write
rows_for = integer(length(my_list))
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) rows_for[i] = nrow(my_list[[i]])
```

But the more complex your task gets, the more readable a `for` loop becomes compared to an alternative like these. In your case, I'd prefer the `for` loop.

---

For more reading on this, see the old question [Is apply more than syntactic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2276001/903061). Since those answers were written, R has been upgraded to include a just-in-time compiler, which further speeds up `for` loops relative to apply. In the nearly 10-year-old answers there, you'll see that *sometimes* `*apply` is *slightly* faster than a `for` loop. Since the JIT compiler, I think you'll find the opposite: *most* of the time a `for` loop is *slightly* faster than `*apply`.

But in both of those cases, unless you're doing something *absolutely trivial* inside the for/apply, **whatever you do inside for/apply will dominate the timings**.

Comment: is there a way to make this work efficiently and neatly to get all of the columns I'd want? Like to specify I want the gender and the happiness column? I'd prefer to do this without a loop inside a loop

Comment: Probably? I don't really know `igraph` or the `set_vertex_attr` function, I just know how loops and apply functions work. What you're asking about sounds like it depends on how `set_vertex_attr` works and whether you can get multiple columns out of it at once.